# How can I integrate $\sqrt{ \frac{x}{ax^3 + b}}$ analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I calculate  $$\int^1_0\sqrt{\frac{x}{ax^3 + b}} \mathrm  dx$$ **analytically**?

I searched my integral table, but I haven't found the solution.

But using WolframAlpha, I could find the analytic result like this,

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x}{ax^3 + b}} \mathrm dx = \frac{
2 \sqrt{\frac{x}{ax^3+b}} \sqrt{ax^3+b} \log{(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^3 +b} + ax^{3/2})}}{3\sqrt{a}\sqrt{x}} + C \\= \frac{
2\log{(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{ax^3 +b} + ax^{3/2})}}{3\sqrt{a}} + C$$

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: Observe the factor $\;\sqrt{ax^3+b}\;$ cancels, according to what you wrote...

Comment: ...and also cancels the factor $\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint...substitute $u^2=x^3$ and you have a standard $\operatorname{arsinh}$ integral

Comment: @MarkViola thanks!